# Dynamically Added Form Elements Won't Post

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post, dynamic

I have a form in which there are sets of elements that are cloned. The form allows a user to input multiple vehicles, with multiple attributes being cloned (year, make, model, etc). I have successfully cloned the elements and they have unique names. However, after the form is posted, only the elements that were *not* dynamically created get posted and are there by accessible using PHP. If you need to look at my code, I can post it on here, it's just a little lengthy. Thanks!

Comment: better to create jsfiddle.net use case than postin gall your code

Comment: Have you tried alerting the values of the dynamically added elements before the submit?

Comment: There are a lot of possible points of failure here; it will really be best if you post some code (either here or on jsfiddle). The critical code to post is 1) The code that generates the dynamic elements, and 2) the code that posts the form

Comment: I'm getting started with making a jsfiddle. I'll be done in just a sec...

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/DerKc/

I didn't know where to put my php file for the post, so it's commented out under the normal HTML. The dynamically added content is under the Driver Information sub-section.

Answer (score 0):

I had a rough look at your code. I think the problem is after submission of the form. The Elements are dynamically generating properly.

Comment: Thanks @vikas-sharma for taking a look! I'm gonna be honest...this is my first attempt at forms/PHP. I've been messing with HTML/CSS since I was pretty young. Is there another way to get the value of an element other than this way? $element = $_POST['someelement']; echo $element;

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP is rather old, but just in case someone is encountering this problem as well... a way to post dynamically added or modified elements' values to PHP is to use jQuery's `serialize()` (which the OP seems to be using anyway):

```
$( "form" ).submit( function ( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $( this ).attr( "action" ),
        data = $( this ).serialize();
    $.post( url, data ).done( function() {
        // Redirect to a "sent" page or something
    } )
    .fail( function() {
        //etc etc
    } );
});
```