# How do I post an ajax radio value?

Tags: ajax, post

I'm struggling with just getting data from an ajax created radio button to correctly post the data at the click of a submit button, and I'm getting frustrated trying to figure out where I've gone wrong.

Am I wrong in thinking that once the ajax radio buttons have been properly created in my HTML driven website from my ajax backend shown here

```
while(odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $rowCarDeets = odbc_result($rs, 'CarDescript');
    $response = $response . "<input type='radio' name='CarDescription' value='" . $rowCarDeets . "'>". $rowCarDeets . "</input></br>";
}
```

That all I need to do is grab it with a $_POST['CarDescription']? I have very little experience working with this, so if there is something that is supposed to be very obvious I need to add, please don't hesitate to suggest it just in case I did forget.

Just as a note, everything else in the form (not provided via ajax, simply taking user input) that these radio buttons are in get posted perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `$_POST`, you should be able to just get the checked value by using the element's name attribute.

so: `$_POST['CarDescription']`

Comment: Yeah that's what I've been doing, but unfortunately no luck. I've been at this for about a day now trying to figure out what possibly could have gone wrong. I'm just adding these buttons to a static div in the original form, is there some reason that div wouldn't be posting data? Does it have something to do with the webpage not recognizing/loading these dynamically added elements once the page has been loaded? As I said, they are coming in with the proper values/html when I inspect the HTML code of the website.

Comment: i see. however, that should not be happening. please check to make sure the items are being inserted within the form tags, and that it happens before submission. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246013/dynamically-added-form-elements-wont-post